# Not showing parsed data in Webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, html-parsing, saxparser

I am new in android development.Please see the Attached image also[image]

Please check this url -

```
http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml
```

Please check handout's (Cat_name) cat_desc it is not showing properly in android webview.

I don't know why, can anyone help me or having any idea?

This is my code-

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes 
        attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentTag=localName;
    Log.v("in start elelmet", "in start elelmet");
    if(qName.equals("Table")){
        buffer=new StringBuffer();
        itemTagStarted=true;

        item=new NewsItem();
    }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if(itemTagStarted){
        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_Name")){
            item.setCatname(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }

        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_id")){
            item.setCatid(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }

        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_Desc")){
            buffer.append(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {
    currentTag="";
    if(qName.equals("Table")){
        itemTagStarted=false;
        newsList.add(item);
    }

    if(qName.equals("Cat_Desc")){
        item.setCatdesc(buffer.toString());
        Log.v("Description data",buffer.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    Log.v("parsing completed","parsing completed : array size : "+newsList.size());
}

});
}
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(...)` to set your Cat_Desc value? I tested your site with a simple SAXParser, dumping the output into `loadDataWithBaseURL` and got a displayable output in the WebView.

[image]

***Updated with the desired tag***

Comment: Dude, my problem is in showing the "Handouts" Tag.. all others are showing perfectly.. can u try with Handouts also... Thanks